# ldap netgroup refresh interval in SSSD

Tags: sssd

sssd has the following config to set the interval for the sudo rules refresh:

```
ldap_sudo_full_refresh_interval
```

What is the configuration to set the interval for the netgroup definition retrieval from LDAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following configuration item in the sssd.conf to control this:

```
entry_cache_timeout = {time in seconds}
```

e.g.

```
entry_cache_timeout = 30
```

Comment: Note to future readers: This controls the default timeout for *all* cache entries, so set with care.